# Tried to replace an emulator with a physical device (Android Studio)

Tags: android, sdk, driver, emulation

Genymotion and the **Android emulators** weren't working, so I decided to use a physical device to test apps. I have a Windows Laptop *(Lenovo)*. I have a *Samsung Galaxy S Lite*, and I think I did the right things (Checked USB debugging on phone, downloaded necessary driver, plugged phone in to computer), and when I run my app in Studio, my phone shows up. However, when I select it and press "OK", nothing happens on my phone. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by "Genymotion and the Android emulators weren't working"?

Comment: Do you have a Launcher activity?

Comment: Genymotion viritual devices weren't loading, but I have someone helping me out now. What's a Launcher activity?

Comment: An Activity with `android.intent.category.LAUNCHER` intent-filter.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to run your application  in samsung you have to install KIES software in your PC.  you can download latest software from [here](http://www.samsung.com/in/support/usefulsoftware/KIES/)

Answer (score 0):

I figured what was going on - I was getting an error, and I didn't see it! I simply remade the project and made sure the package name had no capital letters, and it ran perfectly!